# Is it possible to drag and drop rows between two grids in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

[image: drag and drop]Is it possible to drag-and-drop rows between two grids in asp.net as in the image using jquery/ajax.If so is there any samples available for this.

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dojo_Drag%20And%20Drop_Lists

Also http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Also http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Can be done using Jquery.

Comment: those samples are for lists only..for grid?

Comment: basically Grid itself generate table in HTML when its render.If you go to the View source you can find it there. You have to put class and jquery logic accordingly to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Rad controls than you can use two Rad grids at a time for dragging and dropping. for more details go through this link
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx